# get com.android.volley.servererror with null response

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to upload photo from gallery. When I upload image captured from camera from gallery this error occur.

volley code is as below:

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(upload.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){
        protected Map<String,String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("photo",str_photo);
            params.put("title",str_caption);
            params.put("name",str_caption);
            params.put("admin_id",admin_id);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(upload.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

logcat is as below

```
06-28 10:24:43.442 8774-10428/laurel.wedding E/Volley: [1802] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 413 for http://teachieparentine.com/Wedding_App/photo_upload.php
```

Comment: Have you tried the same api using Postman?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below link for uploading image using volley using multipart...

[How to upload Image on server using Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703655/how-to-upload-image-on-server-using-volley)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in onErrorResponse() function, and update the post

```
error.printStackTrace()
```